Deploy MERN app on cpanel and whm using physical server
I am trying to install my development project on server for production throw cpanel and whm, server is physical and I am using ubuntu, what is the steps, without affecting any other deployed websites, note that apache is installed by default at cpanel.
I am using nodejs, express, react and mysql.
I've installed mysql and node and pm2 and i've connected to mysql in my node app successfully, now i am stuck on deploying my node app in the wright place without editing any ports or affect any other websites and connect it to my react app.
Note: I have the access for the WHM and cPanel.
I have tried with nginx, my server worked but the other deployed websites gone crashed, then I've discovered that I've killed the main port 80 by mistake when i was trying to install nginx, so that all the websites crashed.
Now i want to run my project on my physical server and apply ssh on it without affecting any other ports or websites.
